# Integrate producing bad result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, and fixed in 10.2**

---

I noticed a bug in *Mathematica*. It computes incorrectly a definite integral

```
Integrate[y* Sqrt[(l1^2 - y^2) (l2^2 - y^2)]/(a^2 - y^2), {y, 0, l1}, 
  Assumptions -> l2 > a > l1 > 0]
```

and the response was `(l1 l2)/2`.

The result of integration is obviously incorrect. I sent them an e-mail and reminder. They do not respond. So, I believe the users should know about the bug.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this should be posted on the main site if it is truly a bug.

Comment: On Mathematica 10.4.1 I get `(2*l1*l2 - 2*Sqrt[(a^2 - l1^2)*(-a^2 + l2^2)]*Pi - (4*I)*Sqrt[(a^2 - l1^2)*(-a^2 + l2^2)]*Log[a] +
  2*(-2*a^2 + l1^2 + l2^2)*Log[l1 + l2] + 2*a^2*Log[-l1^2 + l2^2] - l1^2*Log[-l1^2 + l2^2] -
  l2^2*Log[-l1^2 + l2^2] - (2*I)*Sqrt[(a^2 - l1^2)*(-a^2 + l2^2)]*Log[-l1^2 + l2^2] +
  (2*I)*Sqrt[-((a^2 - l1^2)*(a^2 - l2^2))]*
   Log[-(a^2*(l1^2 + l2^2)) + 2*l1*l2*(l1*l2 - I*Sqrt[(a^2 - l1^2)*(-a^2 + l2^2)])])/4`

Comment: @RolfMertig So it does appear to be fixed I'm on 10.0.0.0 with `(l1 l2)/2`.

Comment: @William Yep. People really should always say which Mathematica version they use. And for the notebook FrontEnd also the operating system.

Comment: With `10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)`, `Assuming[{l2 > a > l1 > 0},
 Integrate[y*Sqrt[(l1^2 - y^2) (l2^2 - y^2)]/(a^2 - y^2),
   {y, 0, l1}] // FullSimplify]` evaluates to `(1/2)*(l1*l2 - 
      Sqrt[(a - l1)*(a + l1)*
            (-a^2 + l2^2)]*Pi + 
      (-2*a^2 + l1^2 + l2^2)*
        ArcTanh[l1/l2] - 
      I*Sqrt[(-(a - l1))*(a + l1)*
            (a - l2)*(a + l2)]*
        (2*Log[a] + Log[-l1^2 + l2^2] - 
           Log[(-a^2)*(l1^2 + l2^2) + 
               2*l1*l2*(l1*l2 - 
                    I*Sqrt[(a - l1)*(a + l1)*
                          (-a^2 + l2^2)])]))`

Comment: You should consider changing the title into something more specific. At the moment it is very generic.